# Create Oval Python Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create this shape in python tkinter:
[image]

Yet the only options I have to use are

```
canvas.create_polygon
canvas.create_line
canvas.create_arc
canvas.create_oval
```

None of these options above have the capability to generate such shape. Are there any alternatives or ways I can create this shape using these options?

Comment: I believe they can be created via [`Canvas.create_arc()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20181209012105id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_arc.html).

Comment: What you describe is literally an arc.

Comment: @BryanOakley When I have used Arc, it creates a line at the bottom as an outline to the arc - how can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 2):

As @martineau comments, `create_arc()` is the method but understanding tkinter's `create_oval()` is crucial as an arc is a slice of an oval:

```
import tkinter as tk

WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600, 300
OVAL_WIDTH, OVAL_HEIGHT = 576, 290

# (x0, y0, x1, y1) rectangle for oval
BOUNDS = ( \
    (WINDOW_WIDTH - OVAL_WIDTH) / 2, \
    (WINDOW_HEIGHT - OVAL_HEIGHT) / 2, \
    3*WINDOW_WIDTH/2 - OVAL_WIDTH/2, \
    3*WINDOW_HEIGHT/2 - OVAL_HEIGHT/2 \
)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WINDOW_WIDTH+20, height=WINDOW_HEIGHT+20)  # +20 for window "chrome"
canvas.pack()

rectangle = canvas.create_rectangle(*BOUNDS, outline="blue")  # just for illustration
oval = canvas.create_oval(*BOUNDS, outline="red")  # just for illustration
arc = canvas.create_arc(*BOUNDS, start=30, extent=120, style=tk.ARC, width=3)

root.after(3000, canvas.delete, rectangle)  # remove rectangle illustration
root.after(6000, canvas.delete, oval)  # remove oval illustration

root.mainloop()
```

> When I have used Arc, it creates a line at the bottom as an outline to
>   the arc - how can I get rid of this?

The `style=tk.ARC` above takes care of this -- the default is a pie slice.

[image]

How the ends of this arc terminate aren't identical to your illustration.  As far as I can tell, tkinter's `capstyle` and `joinstyle` options aren't available to arcs.

Comment: I am confused on the purpose of the BOUNDS variable - what is it doing?

Comment: @jakethefake, `BOUNDS` defines the rectangle that defines the oval.  The arc is a slice of this oval.  I'll update my code to illustrate this as well.

Comment: The use of the rectangle has helped me understand. Is there anyway to have the circle start in a corner of the rectangle, and end in the opposite corner?

Answer (score 2):

The `create_arc` method is what you want to use. It creates an arc in one of three different styles, specified by the `style` parameter. This is how the [official tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M111) describes the `style` option:

> If type is **pieslice** (the default) then the arc's region is defined by a section of the oval's perimeter plus two line segments, one between the center of the oval and each end of the perimeter section. If type is **chord** then the arc's region is defined by a section of the oval's perimeter plus a single line segment connecting the two end points of the perimeter section. If type is **arc** then the arc's region consists of a section of the perimeter alone. In this last case the **fill** option is ignored.

Here's an example of the three styles:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, background="black")
canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

canvas.create_arc(0, 20, 100, 120, outline="red", style="pieslice")
canvas.create_arc(80, 20, 180, 120, outline="red", style="chord")
canvas.create_arc(160, 20, 260, 120, outline="red", style="arc")
root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: When you created the 3rd arc using (160, 20, 260, 120) - are those the coordinates of the canvas?

Comment: @jakethefake: the coordinates give the coordinates of two diagonally opposite corners of a rectangular region enclosing the oval that defines the arc.

Comment: I see, is there anyway I can get the arc to start at one corner of the rectangle and end at the diagonal corner of the rectangle? Using `start`?

Comment: @jakethefake: why don't you just do a few experiments with all of the available options? The short answer is that you can create any arc that mathematics will allow.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

coord = 10, 50, 240, 210
arc = canvas.create_arc(coord, start=30, extent=120, style=tk.ARC, width=3)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]